# Magento 2 and filtered collections

Tags: magento2, collection, grid

I have a collection of users and I want to create a backend grid to show only some user depending on a filter.

For example I want to show all the users in my table whith age greater than 18.

I created a new collection and i added my filter to `_initSelect` method.

```
...
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->addUsersFilter();

    return $this;
}
...
public function addUsersFilter()
{
    $this
        ->addFieldToFilter('age', ['gteq' => 18]);

    return $this;
}
...
```

Bt my grid keeps showing me the whole table content regardless my filter.

Does anyone knows how to filter a grid directly from its source collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found it by myself. Posting here if it helps:

This kind of filter cannot be done at collection level, but only at **data provider level**.

So, if you have:

```
<virtualType name="My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Items\Collection"
             type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">my_table</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel"
                  xsi:type="string">My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Items\Collection</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

You can just point to your **custom data provider** instead of inheriting from `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult`.

Your XML becomes:

```
<virtualType name="My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Items\Collection"
             type="My\Module\Ui\Component\DataProvider\SearchResult\Items">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">my_table</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel"
                  xsi:type="string">My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Items\Collection</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Now we are referring to `My\Module\Ui\Component\DataProvider\SearchResult\Items` instead of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult`.

Now we have to create our new class:

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Ui\Component\DataProvider\SearchResult;

class Items extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->addMyCustomFilter();

        return $this;
    }

    public function addMyCustomFilter()
    {
        $this
            ->addFieldToFilter('age', ['gteq' => 18])

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

when I passing dynamic value from URL like:

```
 $nameURL = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 ... do something with $nameURL and get value: $name = "myname"
 and code:
  $this->addFieldToFilter('name', ['eq' => $name]); // not working
```